# Infimum of inner product over a closed subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $M\subset H$ a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space H. Suppose $f \in H$ but $f \not\in M^{\perp}$. Show that
$$ \inf_{x\in M,\|x\|=1} (f,x)$$
is attained and the min is unique.

So what I've tried so far was to use extreme value theorem. I know that the closed unit circle is compact with respect to $\sigma(H,H^*)$ due to reflexivity and $M$ is weakly closed as well so the intersection would be weakly compact, EVT would come in here until I realized the infimum is only over the shell intersect M, so my idea stops there.

I also tried constructing a sequence $(f,x_n)$ converging to the infimum, since M is also reflexive and each $x_n$ has norm 1, there exists a weakly convergent subsequence. If $x$ is the weak limit and $\|x\|=1$, I would be done. But I don't know how to show $\|x\|=1$, I do know however $\|x\| \leq 1$ simply by weak convergence.

Just looking for a hint!!
Thank you!

Comment: $\inf \langle f, x \rangle = - \sup \langle f, x \rangle$, so this closely relates to the projection theorem. In particular, it might be helpful to write down which vector actually attains the infimum in question.

Comment: Brezis Exercise 5.11. (For future readers coming from this reference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. As you said we know that the unit ball is weak* compact, so by the EVT there exists $u$ in the closed unit ball so that $\inf_{\|x\|\leq 1}(f,x)=(f,u)$. We also note that $f\neq 0$ so $u\neq 0$. Set $\alpha=1/\|u\|$. We claim that $\inf_{\|x\|=1}(f,x)=(f,\alpha u)$. Assume not: Then there exists a $v$ on the unit sphere such that $(f,v)<(f,\alpha u$). Then $\frac{1}{\alpha}(f,v)<(f,u)$, meaning that $(f,\|u\|v)<(f,u)$, which contradicts the choice of $u$.

This approach, however, is not the best approach in order to see uniqueness. We need to exploit the geometry of the Hilbert space. Note that we can write $f=P_Mf+P_{M^\perp}f$. Thus for any $x\in M$ we have $(f,x)=(P_Mf,x)$. Combining this with Cauchy-Schwarz, we see that
$$\inf_{\|x\|=1}(f,x)\geq-\|P_Mf\|.$$
Clearly this infimum is achieved at $x=\frac{-P_Mf}{\|P_Mf\|}.$ Finally we remember that equality is achieved in Cauchy-Schwarz if and only if the two elements are linearly dependent. I.e. for any $x,y\in H$ $|(y,x)|=\|y\|\|x\|$ if and only if $x=\alpha y$. As any ray only intersects the unit sphere at a unique point, we are done.

Comment: ahhh right. Dang, I was so close, just unwilling to commit to the idea hahaha. Thank you so much tho!

Comment: @Asukev We have all been there!

Comment: would you know how to show uniqueness? Just a hint would be fine.

Comment: @Asukev Sorry my last hint was actually sending you down a difficult path. See the edit.

Comment: forgot to update this, but I found another way. Assuming two points along the sphere are both minimizers then taking any convex combination will give a line of points in the ball that are equal to the min. But if you normalize points along this line, then you get an even smaller minimum, which is the contradiction